# React hooks onClick icon change is not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to change my icon onClick. But for some that is not working. What I have done is that, if there is submenuIcon1, it will be rendered. If someone clicks on the submenu option, it will render the submenuIcon2, based on the clicked variable.
Maybe I have done something wrong in the ternary operations. Please can someone help me regarding this? 
**Required Behavior** 
Whenever clicking on the submenu options, the icon will change. In this case it will be from submenuIcon1 to submenuIcon2. 
**Current Behavior** 
Clicking on the submenu options, the icon doesn't change. 
What I have done so far is that,

```
export default function Sidebar() {
  const [selectedSubMenu, setSelectedSubMenu] = useState("");
  const [clicked, setClicked] = useState(false);
  let location = useLocation();

  const handleClick = (title) => {
    setClicked(!clicked);
    if (title === selectedSubMenu) {
      setSelectedSubMenu("");
    } else {
      setSelectedSubMenu(title);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Box
        display='flex'
        justifyContent='flex-start'
        alignItems='flex-start'
        mb={10}
      >
        <Box>
          {sidebarItems.map((items) => {
            return (
              <Box
                width='200px'
                textAlign='start'
                cursor='pointer'
                onClick={() => {
                  handleClick(items.title);
                  
                }}
                fontFamily='Fjord One'
                boxShadow='lg'
                _hover={{
                  bgColor: "#1a2963",
                  color: "white",
                }}
                key={items.title}
              >
                <Link
                  to={items.url}
                  as={RouterLink}
                  width='100%'
                  _focus={{
                    boxShadow: "none",
                  }}
                  style={{ textDecoration: "none" }}
                >
                  <Box display='flex' justifyContent='space-between'>
                    <Text fontSize='xl' alignItems='flex-start'>
                      {items.title}
                    </Text>
                 //ternary operation
                    {!!items.submenuIcon1 ? (
                      <Box alignItems='flex-start'>{items.submenuIcon1}</Box>
                    ) : clicked ? (
                      <Box alignItems='flex-start'>{items.submenuIcon2}</Box>
                    ) : (
                      <Box></Box>
                    )}
                  </Box>
                </Link>

                <Collapse
                  in={items.title === selectedSubMenu}
                  transition={{ enter: { delay: 0.1 }, exit: { delay: 0.1 } }}
                >
                 
                </Collapse>
              </Box>
            );
          })}
        </Box>

        <Box width='100%'>
          <TransitionGroup>
            <CSSTransition
              key={location.pathname}
              classNames='fade'
              timeout={300}
            >
              <Routes location={location.pathname}>
              //routes
              </Routes>
            </CSSTransition>
          </TransitionGroup>
        </Box>
      </Box>
    </div>
  );
}
```

My sidebarItems array

```
import { AddIcon, MinusIcon } from "@chakra-ui/icons";

const sidebarItems = [
  {
    title: "Introduction",
    url: "/",
  },
  {
    title: "Dummy",
    url: "/Dummy",
    submenuIcon1: <AddIcon w={5} h={3} />,
    submenuIcon2: <MinusIcon w={5} h={3} />,
      
    

    subMenu: [
      {
        title: "Dummy",
        url: "/Dummy",
      },
      {
        title: "Dummy",
        url: "/Dummy",
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    title: "Dummy",
    url: "/Dummy",
    submenuIcon1: <AddIcon w={5} h={3} />,
    submenuIcon2: <MinusIcon w={5} h={3} />,
    
    subMenu: [
      {
        title: "Dummy",
        url: "/Dummy",
      },
      {
        title: "Dummy",
        url: "/Dummy",
      },
    ],
  },

  {
    title: "Dummy",
    url: "/Dummy",
    submenuIcon1: <AddIcon w={5} h={3} />,
    submenuIcon2: <MinusIcon w={5} h={3} />,
    
    subMenu: [
      {
        title: "Dummy",
        url: "/Dummy",
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    title: "News",
    url: "/news",
  },
  {
    title: "Contact Us",
    url: "/contacts",
  },
];

export default sidebarItems;
```

Comment: that's so much code... add a minimal example

Comment: @OmriAttiya can you check now? I also added some comments

Comment: there's no menuItem (`items`) that has  `submenuIcon2` but doesn't have `submenuIcon1` so in your ternary `!!items.submenuIcon1` is always true, so it will always display `items.submenuIcon1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so I fixed it by adding the following.

```
import { AddIcon, MinusIcon } from "@chakra-ui/icons";
 {items.subMenu && (
                      <Box alignItems='flex-start'>
                        {selectedSubMenu === items.title ? (
                          <MinusIcon w={5} h={3} />
                        ) : (
                          <AddIcon w={5} h={3} />
                        )}
                      </Box>
                    )}
```

imported icons in the main sidebar component

Answer (score 0):

Try the following. I fixed some lines of your code.

```
  return (
    <>
      <Box
        width='200px'
        height='160px'
        textAlign='start'
        bgColor='#473198'
        px={5}
        borderRadius={2}
      >
        <Text fontSize='2xl' color='white' fontFamily='Fjord One'>
         Some title
        </Text>
      </Box>
    </>
  );
};

export default function Sidebar() {
  const [selectedSubMenu, setSelectedSubMenu] = useState("");
  const [clicked, setClicked] = useState(false);
  let location = useLocation();

  const handleClick = (title) => {
    setClicked(!clicked);
    if (title === selectedSubMenu) {
      setSelectedSubMenu("");
    } else {
      setSelectedSubMenu(title);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Box
        display='flex'
        justifyContent='flex-start'
        alignItems='flex-start'
        mb={10}
      >
        <Box>
          <SidebarTitle />
          {sidebarItems.map((items) => {
            return (
              <Box
                width='200px'
                textAlign='start'
                cursor='pointer'
                onClick={() => {
                  handleClick(items.title);
                  
                }}
                fontFamily='Fjord One'
                boxShadow='lg'
                _hover={{
                  bgColor: "#1a2963",
                  color: "white",
                }}
                key={items.title}
              >
                <Link
                  to={items.url}
                  as={RouterLink}
                  width='100%'
                  _focus={{
                    boxShadow: "none",
                  }}
                  style={{ textDecoration: "none" }}
                >
                  <Box display='flex' justifyContent='space-between'>
                    <Text fontSize='xl' alignItems='flex-start'>
                      {items.title}
                    </Text>
                      {selectedSubMenu && (
                      <Box alignItems='flex-start'>{clicked ? items.submenuIcon1 : items.submenuIcon2}</Box>
                    )}
                  </Box>
                </Link>

                <Collapse
                  in={items.title === selectedSubMenu}
                  transition={{ enter: { delay: 0.1 }, exit: { delay: 0.1 } }}
                >
                  {items.subMenu?.map((item) => {
                    return (
                      <Box
                        bgColor='#e4e8e5'
                        boxShadow='md'
                        textAlign='start'
                        width='200px'
                        color='black'
                        _hover={{
                          bgColor: "#666666",
                          color: "white",
                        }}
                        key={item.title}
                        onClick={(event) => {
                          event.stopPropagation();
                        }}
                      >
                        <Link
                          to={item.url}
                          as={RouterLink}
                          width='100%'
                          _focus={{
                            boxShadow: "none",
                          }}
                          style={{ textDecoration: "none" }}
                        >
                          <Text fontFamily='Fjord One'>{item.title} </Text>
                        </Link>
                      </Box>
                    );
                  })}
                </Collapse>
              </Box>
            );
          })}
        </Box>

        <Box width='100%'>
          <TransitionGroup>
            <CSSTransition
              key={location.pathname}
              classNames='fade'
              timeout={300}
            >
              <Routes location={location.pathname}>
              //routes
              </Routes>
            </CSSTransition>
          </TransitionGroup>
        </Box>
      </Box>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: well this solution is changing all the icons at the same time.  But I wanted to change only the selected icon.

Comment: all icons? You only have two options: `plus` and `minus` icons. I guess it is enough to change from one to another when it is clicked

Comment: yes it is changing the icon. But everything is becoming plus or minus. Not only the selected one is changing. wanted to change only the icon of the selected option

Comment: in this case, I updated my answer) try that

Comment: still the same output. also you didn't write what would happen if there is no selectedSubmenu, I mean no mention of ":", so its showing a syntax error on editor

Comment: ohh I edited once. there was typo mistake

Comment: so I fixed it by 
```
 {items.subMenu && (
                      <Box alignItems='flex-start'>
                        {selectedSubMenu === items.title ? (
                          <MinusIcon w={5} h={3} />
                        ) : (
                          <AddIcon w={5} h={3} />
                        )}
                      </Box>
                    )}
```